# Get information from a .txt file

Tags: python, string, list, character

I have a `.txt` file with a list in it (here is an example of the list):

```
[[[[1155, 87]], [[1155, 612]], [[385, -81]], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [151, 130, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [22, 31, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [[2, 3], [1, 3], [3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I would like to get this list back into my program, so I open the file:

```
file = open(file.txt).read()
```

then I try to get it in my program:
`a = file`,
 but I have a character string and not a list, for example `a[0]` returns the first character of the string :[.  So for me there are 2 options: either I don't know how to open and use a `.txt` file, or I have to get back my list with a loop but it seems complicated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("file.txt") as f:
    lst = literal_eval(f.read())
```

Comment: I was about to answer, but I didn't know about `literal_eval`. That's a really awesome solution.

Comment: I tried and i have a big fat error: File "d:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\space invaders\propre\level edit2.py", line 711, in leveleditor
    lst = literal_eval(f.read)
  File "d:\Program Files\python\lib\ast.py", line 87, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "d:\Program Files\python\lib\ast.py", line 86, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <built-in method read of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x02B4ED50>

Comment: @Philipe, You seem to be passing a reference to a method not f.read(), have you used `literal_eval(f.read) <- missing parens`?

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham oh you are totally right my bad i forgot i had multiples lists in the file i've only took one to simplify it worked with only one list in the file, thx you very much i think i can now manage with multiples lists in the txt file

Comment: If you have multiple lists, you just need to call literal_eval on each line when you iterate over f.